# Why are domains not formed in paramagnetic materials?

Tags: solid-state-physics, ferromagnetism

Why are domains formed in ferromagnetic materials, but not in paramagnetic ones?

Comment: Welcome on the PSE! I think, your second question is not related to the first, and if you have multiple questions, you should post them one by one. In order to save your post, I removed that second part, but if you disagree it, feel free to roll it back. Note also, your question should survive a review process, I think now it has a quite good chance for that. I tuned your question a little bit, hopefully so it will be okay. First, I would suggest to invest some effort to handle your this question, then ask the rest. Good luck on the site!

Comment: Seems to me that the question should be turned around. Rather than asking why domains are not formed in paramagnetic (and diamagnetic) materials, why aren't you asking why magnetic domains are formed in ferromagnetic materials? Actually, the reason for that is covered in many physics and materials science textbooks, and it should then be apparent why magnetic domains don't form in paramagnetic and diamagnetic materials.

Comment: @Samuel It depends on the level of the text in question. Handwavy texts quite often introduce ferromagnetic domains like they’re the most obvious thing in the world (and not the awesome field-theoretic constructs that they actually are). From this point of view, such a question might indeed appear perfectly natural.

Answer (score 1):

Domains *do* form in paramagnetic materials. The distinguishing feature of a ferromagnet is that one single domain grows extensively as the system gets larger. But for a finite-size system near the (corresponding infinite system's) phase transition, the two phases behave identically if you only look at small local clusters of spins.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer to the question “Why are domains formed in ferromagnetic materials, but not in paramagnetic ones?” is because if domains were formed in a paramagnetic material then it would be ferromagnetic.

I suppose that the real question you have is “What is the difference between ferromagnetic materials and paramagnetic materials that causes formation of domains in one and not in the other?”

Both paramagnetic and ferromagnetic materials have unpaired spins that give individual atoms a magnetic moment. The difference is due to the collective behavior. In paramagnetic materials the atoms align innreaponse to an external magnetic field, but in ferromagnetic materials the alignment is spontaneous.

There are two competing effects. Roughly speaking when the unpaired spins of neighboring atoms are aligned then the Pauli exclusion principle keeps them further away from each other which reduces their electrostatic energy. On the other hand when the unpaired spins of neighboring atoms are antiparallel their magnetic energy is reduced.

The behavior then is based on which competing effect is stronger. For ferromagnetic materials the first effect is stronger. The domains are caused as the atoms go to the lowest energy state which has aligned magnetic moments to reduce the electrostatic energy.

Comment: You seem to describe not paramagnetism but antiferromagnetic ordering. (In which there are domains too.)

Comment: What then determines the orientation of each domain? Why don't all domains have the same orientation?